# Conditionally add or omit JavaScript properties within c3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, properties, c3.js

I am using a single function to bind multiple [C3](http://c3js.org/) charts.

When using a gauge chart type, a [threshold](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html) value is required. This property is undesired for other chart types.

**How can the threshold property be omitted or added conditionally?**

```js
function bindChart(chartType) {
  let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#Demo',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['A', 95],
        ['B', 65],
        ['C', 11]
      ],
      type: chartType,
    },
    color: {
      pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00'],
      threshold: {
        values: [0, 50, 75, 100], //For gauge
      }
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.4/c3.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="bindChart('pie');">PIE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('gauge');">GAUGE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('bar');">BAR</button>

<div id="Demo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an initial object and then simply with *if/then* add the `threshold` if it is a `gauge` before pass it to `c3.generate()`.

Stack snippet

```js
function bindChart(chartType) {
  let _chart = {
    bindto: '#Demo',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['A', 95],
        ['B', 65],
        ['C', 11]
      ],
      type: chartType,
    },
    color: {
      pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00']      
    }
  }
  
  if (chartType == 'gauge') {
    _chart.color.threshold = { values : [0, 50, 75, 100] }
  };

  let chart = c3.generate(_chart);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.4/c3.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="bindChart('pie');">PIE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('gauge');">GAUGE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('bar');">BAR</button>

<div id="Demo" />
```

---

Or test it inline with something like this, though I don't know if it will be fine having `threshold` still in the object, empty though

```js
function bindChart(chartType) {
  let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#Demo',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['A', 95],
        ['B', 65],
        ['C', 11]
      ],
      type: chartType,
    },
    color: {
      pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00'],
      threshold: ((chartType == 'gauge') ? {values: [0, 50, 75, 100]} : {})
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.4/c3.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="bindChart('pie');">PIE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('gauge');">GAUGE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('bar');">BAR</button>

<div id="Demo" />
```

---

And if not, maybe like this

```js
function bindChart(chartType) {
  let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#Demo',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['A', 95],
        ['B', 65],
        ['C', 11]
      ],
      type: chartType,
    },
    color: ((chartType == 'gauge') ? 
      { pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00'],
        threshold: {values: [0, 50, 75, 100]}} :
      { pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00'] }
      )
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.4/c3.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="bindChart('pie');">PIE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('gauge');">GAUGE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('bar');">BAR</button>

<div id="Demo" />
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was trying to achieve but couldn't determine how to insert conditional statements inside a property. Nice simple answer!

Comment: @Obsidian Thanks ... and I added a 2nd _inline_ version

Comment: Inline is better, in my opinion but I it would depend on the size of the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You can build an object first with all common keys, then you can conditionally add any new keys that you may need.

```js
function bindChart(chartType) {
  // Build base object with common keys
  let colorOptions = {
    pattern: ['#af5', '#ad3', '#a80', '#a00']
  };
  // Assuming the check is for the chartType to be guage
  if (chartType === 'gauge') {
    // Conditionally add new keys
    colorOptions.threshold = {
      values: [0, 50, 75, 100], //For gauge
    }
  }
  let chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#Demo',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['A', 95],
        ['B', 65],
        ['C', 11]
      ],
      type: chartType,
    },
    color: colorOptions,
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.4/c3.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="bindChart('pie');">PIE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('gauge');">GAUGE</button>
<button onclick="bindChart('bar');">BAR</button>

<div id="Demo" />
```